# How to precompile views in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I set up my solution according to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/self-contained-ui-running-one-aspnet-core-mvc-site). I left out some of the things because according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x), ASP.NET Core 2.0 precompiles views by default. In the end, I publish it to a folder, which ends successfully, but my precompiledviews.dll is missing. I tried setting it explicitly in .csproj, but no luck.

Edit: Both of the projects inside the solution are just default MVC templates.

Comment: what is your `TargetFramework`? And have you tried to implicitly set `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` to true?

Comment: @Set , it's Core 2.0, and yes, I did try setting MvcRazorCompileOnPublish to true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I bet you use [Self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd), i.e. publish with command like

> dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win-x64

that results to executable file with all dependencies including .NET Core binaries.

[Razor view compilation and precompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x) article contains following warning:

> Razor view precompilation is currently unavailable when performing a
>   self-contained deployment (SCD) in ASP.NET Core 2.0. The feature will
>   be available for SCDs when 2.1 releases.

So if you want to use precompiled Razor views, you should use [Framework-dependent deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd), i.e. publish with the following command:

> dotnet publish --configuration Release

In this case Razor views are precompiled (by default) and you will find `YourAppName.PrecompiledViews.dll` among other application binaries.

**UPDATE** (for Precompiled Views in Library project)

My original answer relates to usual ASP.NET Core MVC application, however the question is specific to project library holding precompiled views aka Self-Contained UI.

ASP.NET Core precompiles views by default during the publish, however this is not the case for the views stored in library project. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/187) devoted to this problem. That discussion is pretty much long, however it [ends up](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/187#issuecomment-337073175) with the conclusion that for this moment we still need to use solution with custom targets for Razor Views precompilation. It basically the same approach as described in the [article](https://dzone.com/articles/self-contained-ui-running-one-aspnet-core-mvc-site) referenced by the question.

I've setup test solution with `ChildApplication` and main `MvcApplication` and made precompiled views working both for the build and publish.

Here is csproj for `ChildApplication` (skipping sections of default ASP.NET Core MVC project):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- ... -->

<Target Name="SetMvcRazorOutputPath">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MvcRazorOutputPath>$(OutputPath)</MvcRazorOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="_MvcRazorPrecompileOnBuild" DependsOnTargets="SetMvcRazorOutputPath;MvcRazorPrecompile" AfterTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' " />
<Target Name="IncludePrecompiledViewsInPublishOutput" DependsOnTargets="_MvcRazorPrecompileOnBuild" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_PrecompiledViewsOutput Include="$(MvcRazorOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).PrecompiledViews.dll" />
        <_PrecompiledViewsOutput Include="$(MvcRazorOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).PrecompiledViews.pdb" />
        <ContentWithTargetPath Include="@(_PrecompiledViewsOutput->'%(FullPath)')" RelativePath="%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Identity)" TargetPath="%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Filename)%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Extension)" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Here is csproj for parent `MvcApplication`:

```
<!-- ... -->

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ChildApplication\ChildApplication.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(ProjectDir)\..\ChildApplication\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\netcoreapp2.0\ChildApplication.PrecompiledViews.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
</Target>

<Target Name="AddPayloadsFolder" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(ProjectDir)\..\ChildApplication\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\netcoreapp2.0\ChildApplication.PrecompiledViews.dll&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
</Target>
```

Dean North in [his original article](https://dzone.com/articles/self-contained-ui-running-one-aspnet-core-mvc-site) adds direct reference to assembly with precompiled views.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DashboardExample.PrecompiledViews">
        <HintPath>..\DashboardExample\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\DashboardExample.PrecompiledViews.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Such approach isn't perfect because it uses assembly built with specific configuration (`Debug` here). In my project file above, I use separate targets that copy `ChildApplication.PrecompiledViews.dll` during the build and publish.

Here is [**Sample Solution on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49579800-Precompiled-Views-In-Library) with both parent and child projects.

Comment: Actually, I did publish it with that command. It does end successfully, but still without precompiledviews.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the sample solution. I downloaded it, tried publishing it. And I get the error message that the ChildApplication.PrecompiledViews.dll can't be copied because it does not exist. And yes, it does not exist. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Do you run `dotnet publish -c Release` command while being in `MvcApplication` directory? It works perfectly fine for me. Here is a [screenshot of publish execution](https://snag.gy/czoTn2.jpg), please compare with output of your run.

Comment: It is working, but the strange thing is that precompiledviews.dll is still nowhere to be found. Shouldn't it be there ?

Comment: Assemblies with precompiled views will have names of `ChildApplication.PrecompiledViews.dll` and `MvcApplication.PrecompiledViews.dll`. Please recheck, they should be there.

Comment: They aren't there. I even used the windows search function (in case I am blind).

Comment: Could you please share screenshot of `dotnet publish` output as I did above?

Comment: This output lacks messages from `xcopy` command. I'm not sure what makes the difference in your configuration, and especially how the application works without precompiled views.

Comment: It's literally your sample solution lol. I will make an app from scratch and experiment with it tomorrow.

Comment: I finally managed to resolve the problem. The precompiledviews.dll was generated, but my antivirus moved it to a different location. I found all of the dll's in that hidden folder (where the antivirus stores all the "dangerous stuff"). That's just... I don't know what to say :D.

Comment: Funny thing is, I even found the dll's that I (unknowingly) generated 5 days ago :D

Answer (score 2):

I usually just add these to the `.csproj`. No need to copy files or any of that mess.

```
    <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</...
       ...
       <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
       <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        ...
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.2.0" />    
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I saw in following article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-2.2 that setting this value to true disables the Razor SDK. If I want to migrate to Razor SDK, will precompilation of views happen out of the box without specifying MvcRazorCompileOnPublish to true?